# Apache Spark - Converting JavaRDD to DataFrame and vice versa, any performance degradation?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating the `JavaRDD<Model>` by reading a text file and mapping each line to Model Class properties.

Then i am converting `JavaRDD<Model>` to `DataFrame` using `sqlContext`.

```
DataFrame fileDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(javaRDD, Model.class);
```

Basically, we are trying to use DataFrame API to improve performance and easy to write.

Is there any performance degradation or will it create the Model Objects again when converting DataFrame to JavaRDD.

The reason i am doing this, i don't see any methods to read text file directly using sqlContext.

Is there any alternate efficient way to do this?

Comment: what about DataFrameReader which you can get with `SQLContext.read()`? It has plenty of methods, json, parquet even text.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk : Thanks, i can see methods for json and parquet, but how to use text file? what's the format for text file?

Comment: each line in the file is treated as new row in DF, there is only one columnt in the DF called "value". You pass the path to the file to the method. If you have a CSV you can use spark-csv library to read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Will it be slower?**

There definitely will be some overhead, although I did not benchmark how much. Why? Because the `createDataFrame` has to:

- use reflection to get the schema for the `DataFrame` (once for the whole RDD)
- map an entity in the RDD to a row record (so it fits the dataframe format) - N time, once per entity in the RDD
- create the actual `DataFrame` object.

**Will it matter?**

I doubt it. The reflection will be really fast as it's just one object and you probably have only a handful fields there.

Will the transformation be slow? Again probably no as you have only a few fields per record to iterate through.

**Alternatives**

But if you are not using that RDD for anything else you have a few options in the [DataFrameReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html) class which can be accessed through `SQLContext.read()`:

- json: several methods [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#json(org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD))
- parquet: [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#parquet(scala.collection.Seq))
- text: [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#text(scala.collection.Seq))

The good thing about 1 and 2 is that you get an actual schema. The last one, you pass the path to the file (like with other two methods) but since the format is not specified Spark does not have any information about the schema -> each line in the file is treated as a new row in the DF with a single column `value` which contains the whole line.

If you have a text file in a format that would allow creating a schema, for instance CSV, you can try using a third party library such as [Spark CSV](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv).